# Merging accounts feature broken

Tags: feature-request, bug

I think the merge account feature is broken? I tried merging two accounts I accidentally created. I received two emails, on clicking the second one, I was presented with a button to merge accounts. On clicking okay, I was presented with a `404 error page`.  Account merging did not take place (both accounts show no changes, no confirmation received either).

[image: After clicking both confirmation links]

Also, another note - on the merge page, I think it uses a fixed heuristic to choose which will be the final account. I suppose we could give an option which one to preserve.  (In my case, I would like to keep the reverse of what is presented). I suppose one could change / add the email later, but an option to choose `merge A into B`  vs `merge B into A` would be good.